# convert compound to atom in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to use `atom_chars/2` on the expression of `3+4`, but I get
`ERROR: atom_chars/2: Type error: 'atom' expected, found '3+4' (a compound)`.

I'm thinking that if I can add `" "` on both sides of the compound, it would work, e.g.

```
atom_chars("3+4", Result).
```

but I don't know how I can do that, or is there other approaches to do this?
Please give me some advice.

EDIT: What I mean is that the input has to be `3+4`, instead of `'3+4'`, so what I want to do is to write a predicate before the atom_chars/2 to convert `3+4` to `'3+4'`.

For instance: for `compound2atom(X,Y)`,

```
-?compound2atom(3+4,Y).
Y='3+4'.
```

Comment: SWI Prolog has `term_string/2`, so `term_string(Term, '3+4')` will give `X = 3 + 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SWI-Prolog, there is [`with_output_to/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2) or [`format/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/3):

```
?- with_output_to(atom(A), write(3+4)).
A = '3+4'.

?- with_output_to(chars(C), write(3+4)).
C = ['3', +, '4'].

?- format(atom(A), "~w", [3+4]).
A = '3+4'.

?- format(chars(C), "~w", [3+4]).
C = ['3', +, '4'].
```

But if you look hard enough you should be able to find some predicate that does that, for example [`term_to_atom/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_to_atom/2).

My personal preference leans towards `format/3`.

Comment: hi, what I mean is that the input has to be `3+4` instead of `'3+4'`, so what can I do to convert it?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really helpful.